# Find classes using an annotation multiple times via IDEA structured find

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, structural-search

I'd like to search for classes, that have at least 3 fields annotated with the @Inject annotation like this:

```
class SpecificUiComponent extends UIComponent {
      @Inject
      MyService1 myservice1;
      @Inject
      MyService2 myservice2;
      @Inject
      MyService3 myservice3;
}
```

I've managed to create a search template that finds classes extending UIComponent AND also have an @Inject annotation in it, however, if I've set the "min" occurrences of the Annotation variable to 3, Intellij still returned classes only having one @Inject.

The reason I'd like to have the above search is to find those UI components, which are having many external defendencies, therefore are overcomplicated and need refactoring. If you have some better way of doing that, please also share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set the minimum occurrences of the field to 3, not of the annotation. This is to find classes with at least three fields with the @Inject annotation, not classes with one field with at least three @Inject annotations. To give a complete example use a pattern as follows:

```
class $Class$ extends $Parent$ { 
  @Inject
  $FieldType$ $Field$;
}
```

Edit variable `field` to have minimum occurrences of `3` and maximum occurrences of `unlimited`.
Variable `parent` should have text/regexp `UIComponent` and the `Apply constraint within type hierarchy` checkbox enabled.

This will find classes extending UIComponent directly or indirectly with at least 3 fields annotated with @Inject.

Comment: Thanks, works great! One note though, for some reason "extends UIComponent" did not work for me to find indirect subclasses. Instead, I've used a variable $Parent$, where I've restricted it to UIComponent and checked the "Apply constraint within type hierarchy" checkbox.

Comment: By the way, could you give some background info on why it works this way? It's not very clear to me, why the occurrence of 3 has to be on the field name and not on the annotation / type.

Comment: I have edited my answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to **Edit -> Find -> Find in path** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
- Enter `@Inject[\S\s]*@Inject[\S\s]*@Inject` as the search phrase.

(Make sure you have ticked `Regular Expression` under `General` in `Find in path` menu. :)) )

to filter the classes only which extends UIComponent, you can use `extends UIComponent[\S\s]*@Inject[\S\s]*@Inject[\S\s]*@Inject` as your search phrase.

On the other hand, classes which extends UIComponent are supposed to be inside a specific package right? So you can enter that directory as your search path. :))

Comment: Thanks, however how does that restrict the search for classes that extend UIComponent?

Comment: @IstvanDevai I have added to the answer. please check. :))

Comment: I still don't see how this solution would find those classes that only indirectly inherit from UIComponent. Exactly that was the reason I was looking into structural search, that I can match such things that a simple freetext search cannot.

Comment: @IstvanDevai this worked for me. not worked for you? Anyway I agree that Bas got a better answer. :))